# How do I return a component with passed props with R.ifElse?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm diving into ramdajs and refactoring some react code here. It might not necessary to do it in this case but for the sake of exercise how do I pass props in R.ifElse ?

```
{!this.state.repos ? <Loader /> : <RepoGrid repos={this.state.repos} />}

// refactoring to:

{R.ifElse(
   R.isEmpty, 
   R.always(Loader), 
   RepoGrid
)(this.state.repos)}
```

This gives me an error `Cannot read property '@@transducer/step' of null`

```
const ReposGrid = R.pipe(
    R.tap(console.log)
    R.prop("repos"),
    R.map(Repo),
    ReposWraper
)
```

Comment: I don't know what `log` does, but if it's anything like `console.log`, it returns `undefined` and so `prop`  isn't supplied a value.  `R.tap(console.log)` logs and then returns your original value.

Comment: You might want to check out the library [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/), particularly it's [branch](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#branch) function, it has a lot of functional utilities and pairs well with ramda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what it is you're looking for, but it sounds as though you want something like this:

```js
const ReposGrid = repos => `| ${repos.join(' | ')} |`;
const Loader = `Loader`

const transform = R.ifElse(
   R.isEmpty,
   R.always(Loader),
   ReposGrid
)

console.log(transform([])) 
//=> 'Loader'

console.log(transform(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']))
//=> '| foo | bar | baz |'
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

The arguments supplied to the function returned by `ifElse` are supplied to the condition, consequent, and alternative functions.  If this isn't what you want, what do you mean by passing identity to `ReposGrid`?  Should it actually be supplied the identity function? (e.g. `(x) => x`?