# Why `Cannot read property '@@transducer/step' of null`?

Tags: reactjs, ramda.js

I'm diving into ramdajs and refactoring some react code here. It might not necessary to do it in this case but for the sake of exercise I want to refactor this ternary code but get an error.

```
{!this.state.repos ? <Loader /> : <ReposGrid repos={this.state.repos} />}

// refactoring to:

{R.ifElse(R.isEmpty, R.always(Loader), ReposGrid)(this.state.repos)}
```

This gives me an error `Cannot read property '@@transducer/step' of null`

```
const ReposGrid = R.pipe(
    R.tap(console.log)
    R.prop("repos"),
    R.map(Repo),
    ReposWraper
)
```

Comment: Could you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I don't think there is enough information here to investigate.

Comment: If I just uncomment my first solution with ternary operator everything works well. If I use just a solution with Ramda it fails. It seems data is not even passed to ReposGrid

Comment: I demonstrated in [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51996525) that data is passed to the alternative function.  That's why I am looking for more here.  With `pipe` you should be able to comment out all the functions, then uncomment one at a time to see what's being sent at each step.  Or you could `tap(console.log)` after each.